# How to get values of different views for ContextMenu Switch Statement

Tags: android, listview, view, android-contextmenu

I have an `Activity` that uses two `ContextMenu`'s.  One is for long pressing on rows in a `listView`.  Another, if you click on an `ImageView`.  You can only have one `onCreateContextMenu()` method and I need to do different things depending on which `ContextMenu` I open.

On the `ListView`, I need to get a`TextView` -  but this returns `null` if the user clicks on the `ImageView` menu instead.  So I need a `switch` statement then to separate the two.

When I log `View v` going into the `ContextMenu`, I get this:

```
// For the ImageView
04-16 08:36:20.687: D/View:(7152): android.widget.ImageView{426295e0 V.ED..CL ...P.... 20,25-220,225 #7f070093 app:id/ibPP}

//For the ListView
04-16 08:36:20.687: D/View:(7152): android.widget.ListView{425edcb0 VFED..CL .F...... 10,16-710,1134 #102000a android:id/list}
```

So when I do this:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
        case ??????: {
```

What views should I put for the two different case statements?

**UPDATE**. Here is my full code.  I went with `if` instead of `switch`:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId() == android.R.id.list) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Available Actions");

        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

        int position = info.position;
        ListView lv = (ListView) v;
        int firstVisible = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View rowView = lv.getChildAt(position - firstVisible);

        reviewWords = ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.labelComment))
                .getText().toString(); // Crashes here when click ImageView

        menu.add(2, 1, 0, "Edit");
        menu.add(2, 2, 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(2, 3, 0, "Share");

    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.ibPP) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();

        if (userName.equals(Rateit.username)) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile_pic, menu);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you are accessing the label via the listView element. You should be accessing the data directly. You probably have a cursor or an array somewhere containing your labels. Use it

Comment: Yes, I can't believe I didn't think about it.  Can get data from `ListAdapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently, the imageView is `R.id.ibPP` and the listView is `android.R.id.list`

Comment: I think you are right, but it still crashes, see updated code.  I added the entire method.

Comment: crashes => post stacktrace